# How to set spaces in the column names of a table or data frame using xtable

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

So I want to use spaces among words in the names of the columns of a data frame and print the data frame to a pdf in latex format. However, when I use `xtable()` to do this, the names of the columns get joined.

For example, I'd want the title of the second column to look as "Categoria de Referencia". Instead, what I get is:

[image]

Does someone know how to sort this out? Here's the R chunk that translates the data frame into latex:

```
tab<-xtable(dat,caption="Efectos de las Variables sobre la Probabilidad de Conversión",digits=2)
print(tab,latex.environments = "center",include.rownames=FALSE)
```

Here's the code that generates the dataframe:

```
structure(list(Variable = structure(c(4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("App", "Clicker", "País", "Uso"), class = "factor"), 
    Categoría.de.Referencia = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Brasil", "Clicker", "No Acaba Unidad", 
    "No Usa App"), class = "factor"), Categoría.Considerada = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("Acaba la Unidad", 
    "España", "Francia", "ITalia", "Méjico", "No Cliker", "Otros Países", 
    "Usa App"), class = "factor"), Variación = structure(c(8L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("-0.19%", "-0.46%", 
    "-2.32%", "0.31%", "0.46%", "0.7%", "1.15%", "2.08%"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Variable", 
"Categoría.de.Referencia", "Categoría.Considerada", "Variación"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico done, I edited the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use the `sanitize.*` options, e.g.:

```
> print.xtable(xtable(dat),include.rownames=F,
               sanitize.colnames.function=function(x)gsub("\\."," ",x))

% latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Thu Aug 20 10:47:54 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \hline
Variable & Categoría de Referencia & Categoría Considerada & Variación \\ 
  \hline
Uso & No Acaba Unidad & Acaba la Unidad & 2.08\% \\ 
  País & Brasil & España & 0.31\% \\ 
  País & Brasil & Francia & 0.46\% \\ 
  País & Brasil & ITalia & 0.7\% \\ 
  País & Brasil & Méjico & -0.19\% \\ 
  País & Brasil & Otros Países & -0.46\% \\ 
  Clicker & Clicker & No Cliker & -2.32\% \\ 
  App & No Usa App & Usa App & 1.15\% \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

From `?print.xtable`:

> `sanitize.text.function`
>   All non-numeric enteries (except row and column names) are sanitised in an attempt to remove characters which have special meaning for the output format. If `sanitize.text.function` is not `NULL` (the default), it should be a function taking a character vector and returning one, and will be used for the sanitization instead of the default internal function

This is the same for `sanitize.colnames.function`.

Another option in case you'd like a total overhaul of the names (so that you can't `regex` your way to freedom as above) is to convert `dat` to a matrix and set the `colnames`:

```
datmat<-as.matrix(dat)
colnames(datmat)<-c("Variable","Categoría de Referencia",
                    "Categoría Considerada", "Variación")
print.xtable(xtable(datmat),include.rownames=F)
```